# How does push amplification works?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can anyone explain how does push notification amplification works? if service providers, ie. clevertap,  send a notification directly to all the devices which didn't receive push via FCM then why these service providers use FCM in first place at all? why not send notifications directly and guarantee 100% delivery?

Answer (score 3):

The primary motive of Push Amplification is to boost the delivery rate of app push notifications. Though it has several issues why some users are not receiving the push notifications.

> The main reason is the "**OS/Device level restrictions**" which means
>   that the operating system of a certain Chinese OEMs (Xiaomi, Lenovo,
>   Oppo, etc) restricts or 'kills' background processes cutting the
>   device off from **GCM/FCM** an **essential cord** for push
>   notification delivery.

To help to overcome this issue, you can use MoEngage Push Amplification that will act as a fallback to GCM and delivers notifications directly to users’ device thereby reaching those users, who would have been missed by GCM. For more details you can check this from [MoEngagesite site](https://www.moengage.com/blog/moengage-push-amplification-push-delivery-issues/).

Answer (score 0):

I found a clear explanation on how netcore push amplification works?

- Smartech SDK generates a Unique ID for each user to directly deliver
  App Push Notifications.
- With this unique ID, Smartech builds a back-up delivery gateway,
  other than the GCM/FCM & APNS.
- With its pull-back mechanism, Smartech server triggers back all those
  undelivered APNs directly to the user’s smartphone.

[image]

reference : https://netcoresmartech.com/what-is-push-amplification